# Passing query from php to java

Tags: java, php

i em trying to fetch some query from an url and then pass them to a java program for further execution. The problem i am facing is that my php code is calling my java program but is not passing the values.
till now i have worked on these codes,

PHP PROGRAM:

```
<?php
$phonecode= $_GET['phonecode'];
$keyword= $_GET['keyword'];
$location= $_GET['location'];
exec("C:\Users\Abc\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication11\src\javaapplication11\main.java -jar jar/name.jar hello" . $phonecode . ' ' . $keyword . ' ' . $location, $output);
print_r($output);
?>
```

JAVA PROGRAM:

```
public class Main
{

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try
        {
            String phonecode = args[];
            System.out.println(args[]);
            System.out.println(phonecode);// i have only tried to print phonecode for now
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: and what is happening?

Comment: it is calling my java program. But my java program is not printing the value phonecode, so i think its not getting the value from the php command....

Thanks in advance

Comment: There seem to be a few errors here. As it stands that Java file won't compile.

Comment: Wow, that `exec` call is insanely dangerous! What if I tinkered with the `location` uri param, and made it say something like `&& format c: /q`... please [escape shell arguments](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php). ***never trust the network***, oh and your java code really doesn't make much sense

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, a couple of issues with the Java code you've posted, here's a *working* version of what you posted:

```
class Main
{
    public static void main(String[] args)//String[] args, not String args[]
    {
        if (args.length == 0)
        {//check to see if we received arguments
            System.out.println("No arguments");
            return;
        }
        if ( args.length < 3)
        {//and make sure that there are enough args to continue
            System.out.println("To few arguments");
            return;
        }
        try
        {//this try-catch block can be left out
            String phonecode = args[0];//first arg
            String keyword = args[1];//second
            String location = args[2];//third
            //print out the values
            System.out.print("Phonecode: ");
            System.out.println(phonecode);
            System.out.print("keyword: ");
            System.out.println(keyword);
            System.out.print("location: ");
            System.out.println(location);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());//get the exception MESSAGE
        }
    }
}
```

Now, save that as a `.java` file, and **compile** it, it should churn out a `Main.class` file. I compiled it from the command-line:

```
javac main.java
```

I don't have netbeans installed, but I suspect the `.class` file will be written to a different directory, something like:

```
C:\Users\Abc\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication11\bin\javaapplication11\Main.class
                                                     // note the BIN
```

Then, to execute, you need to run the `java` command, and pass it the path to this `Main.class` file, leaving out the `.class` extension. Thus, we end up with:

```
java /path/to/Main 123 keywrd loc
```

Should result in the output:

```
Phonecode: 123
keyword: keywrd
location: loc
```

In your PHP code:

```
exec('java /path/to/Main '.escapeshellarg($phonecode). ' '.escapeshellarg($keyword).' '.escapeshellarg($location), $output, $status);
if ($status === 0)
{//always check exit code, 0 indicates success
    var_dump($output);
}
else
    exit('Error: java exec failed: '.$status);
```

There are a couple of other issues, too: like `$phonecode = $_GET['phonecode'];` doesn't check if that `$_GET` param exists. If it doesn't your code will emit notices. To fix:

```
$phonecode = isset($_GET['phonecode']) ? $_GET['phonecode'] : '';
```

Other niggles include: the backslash is a special char in strings, it is used in escape sequences: `\n` is a newline char. PHP can deal with the *NIX directory separator `/`, even on windows. Use that, or escape the backslashes (`C:\\Users\\Abc\\` and so on).
A file that *only* contains PHP code doesn't require the closing `?>` tag. In fact: [it is recommended you leave it out](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.basic-syntax.phptags.php).

Comment: Thanks a lot man!!!
though i am still stuck a little bit, but you were a lot of help.

Comment: @user3710223: You're welcome, and welcome to the site BTW. Given that you're new: do take the time to read through the _help_ section. Users are asked _not_ to post _"thank you"_-comments. Mark the answer that helped as accepted, instead. cf [What to do when someone answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Comment: hello Elias,
sorry to bother you again, but i em still not able to run my code, I am providing all the information,lyk what i am left with after you told me what to do, please see if you can help me out. 
main class file location: C:\Users\Abc\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication11\src\javaapplication11,
exec command
exec('C:\Users\Abc\Documents\NetBeansProjects\JavaApplication11\src\javaapplication11\main' .escapeshellarg($phonecode). ' '.escapeshellarg($keyword).' '.escapeshellarg($location), $output, $status);  
i didn't understand the part
Then, to execute, you need to run the java..

Comment: Your `exec` command is wrong: you have to tell your system that the compiled code has to be run through java. After compiling, java will generate a file called _"Classname.class"_. if the class name starts with an upper case, then this should be reflected by in your command (`Path/to/Main`, not `Path/to/main`). Most importantly, your command must start with `java`: `exec('java /Path/to/Main '.escapeshellargs($phonecode)...);`

Answer (score 0):

your java code should look like

```
 public static void main (String[] args) {
   for (String s: args) {
     System.out.println(s);
   }
 }
```

Note `String[] args`, not `String args[]`

Also on PHP side in exec you need space between string hello, and variable $phonecode if you want those to be looked as a 2 separate arguments.

Comment: i am sorry i tried everything you told, but it still seems not to work.

Comment: there is another problem coming up that my php code would start netbeans with my java code but won't execute it.

Comment: @user3710223: Does your java code even compile? Because as it stands: `String phonecode = args[];` should give a compiler error

Comment: I'm not a Java developer, but you must compile your project first, make sure you can execute java binary, and only then you can call it from PHP.

Comment: no that gives an compile error, but i thought that's because it is supposed to get the value from the php code which i haven't run yet

Comment: @user3710223: A compiler error indicates that your code is ***wrong***. Bad/invalid code can, by definition, not be executed. If your Java code can't be compiled, then that's what needs to be fixed